# повторная смена изображения

Tags: jquery

есть такой код

```
function fadeImage ()
{
    $('#image').fadeTo(3000,0.1);
    $('#image').fadeTo(3000,1.2);

}
setInterval(fadeImage,3000);
```

(этот код заставляет фотку исчезать и появляться) 
вобщем нужно чтобы после каждого цикла фотка менялась на другую (всего 5 фоток)
и после последней менялась на первую 
если ставить вот так

```
function fadeImage ()
{
    $('#image').fadeTo(3000,0.1);
    $('#image').fadeTo(3000,1.2);
    setInterval($('#image').attr('src','2.jpg'),9000);

}
setInterval(fadeImage,3000);
```

фотка сначала меняется а потом начинает мигать 
кто знает как сделать пожалуйстя помогите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю Вам надо внимательнее прочитать [описание](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) функции и воспользоваться callback'ом, например так:]

```
$('#image').fadeTo(3000,0.1, 
    function(){
       $('#image').fadeTo(3000,1.2, 
        function(){$('#image').attr('src','2.jpg');}
);

}
);
```

Специально для [[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre) :)

Вам, если по хорошему, лучше написать [расширения](http://xdan.ru/Kak-napisat-plagin-na-jQuery.html) для jquery объекта чтобы можно было использовать в виде:

```
$('#image').YouBlinkTo({ interval:3000, minOpacity:0.1, maxOpacity:1.2, newImage:'2.jpg'});
```

А расширение типа такого:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.YouBlinkTo = function( options ) {  
     var settings = { interval: 3000, minOpacity:0.1, maxOpacity:1.2, newImage:'2.jpg' 
     };

  if ( options ) { 
    $.extend( settings, options ); 
  };
    return this.each(function() {

       $(this).fadeTo(
            settings["interval"],
            settings["minOpacity"],
            function(){ 
                $(this).fadeTo(
                    settings["interval"], 
                    settings["maxOpacity"], 
                    function(){
                        $(this).attr('src',settings["newImage"]);
                    });
                    });
    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: спагетти-код

Comment: Не претендую на красоту решения, это дело автора. Главное идея :-) И, кстати, данный стиль кода всё же не подпадает под определение спагетти кода

Comment: @Чад, а где параметры по умолчанию? =)

Comment: :-D Ох, что же делать?!?!

Comment: а где поддержка data-api? шучу, конечно, её можно и самостоятельно реализовать =)

Comment: Ну, тут код не для копи паста а примера :-) Но да, можно развернуться что ух!!!! задать свои теги <blink_img src="1.jpg" newsrc="2.jpg" interval="3000" minOpacity="0.1" maxOpacity="1.2" />